# Date format changes using Joda API

Tags: java, api, timezone, jodatime

I m using joda API in my code but i am unable to show the dates in correct format:
Sample COde:

```
DateTimeZone gmtTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("GMT");
DateTimeZone pstTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago");                
DateTimeFormatter startEndFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").withZone(pstTimeZone);
DateTimeFormatter startEndOutFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").withZone(gmtTimeZone);
DateTimeFormatter batchFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter durationFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("hh:mm:ss");
```

on running the code the time value is changed.
for Example:

```
"30-09-2015 16:21:48"
```

Which should be:

```
"30-09-2015 04:21:48"
```

Comment: Your code creates 4 different formats, but doesn't use them at all. Post a minimal example reproducing the problem. Tell us what you expect that example to do, and what is does instead.

Comment: Try `hh:mm:ss` instead of `HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn java data formatting characters. see following table which i found at [`SimpleDateFormat` Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

[image]

So, 
change your `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`date format into `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss`

Comment: No no no. Joda-Time uses a different set of pattern symbols. It is not the same as used in SimpleDateFormat,

Comment: **INCORRECT** This Answer is incorrect, as Hochschild comment above said. Joda-Time has its own formatting patterns. Quite similar to java.text.SimpleDateFormat but some differences. Don't read a [Yugo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zastava_Koral) repair manual if you own a Honda.